# Calculate the number of roots of $f(z) = e^{z} - e^{-z} + \frac{2}{z-3}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = e^{z} - e^{-z} + \frac{2}{z-3}$ in $\mathbb C$. I have to calculate the number of roots of this function in the subset $A = \left\{ z \in \mathbb C : |Im(z)| < \frac{\pi}{2} \right\}$.

I have thought about using the Rouche's Theorem but I don't know how, as I am used to doing it inside a ball and with a polynomial function.

Thank you in advance